# How to get element from shadow-DOM

Tags: polymer-2.x

I have a problem with accessing to `shadow-root`. I need to get `img` but it doesn't work. Here is my page:

```
<link rel="import" href="/frontend/src/ui/breadcrumb.html">
<dom-module id="bread-crumb">
    <template>
        <style include="breadcrumb"></style>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <template is="dom-if" if="{{pageInfo.title}}">
                <div class="left">
                    <img id="img" src$="{{pageInfo.icon}}">
                    <span>{{pageInfo.title}} <strong>{{pageInfo.part}}</strong></span>
                </div>
            </template>
            <div class="links">
                <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[links]]">
                    <a class$="{{_getSelected(item.selected)}}" href$="{{item.link}}"> {{item.title}} </a>
                </template>
                <!-- <template is="dom-if" if="{{item.title}}">
                    <a href$=""
                </template> -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
    <script>
    class BreadCrumb extends Polymer.Element {
        static get is() {
            return 'bread-crumb'
        }
        _getSelected(selected){
            return selected ? "selected" : "";
        }

        connectedCallback() {
            this._imageHide();
        }

        _imageHide() {
            let image = this.$.img;
            if(image.src == null || image.src == undefined)
                image.classList.add("hidden");
        }
    }

    customElements.define(BreadCrumb.is, BreadCrumb);
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

I tried this also `let image = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#img');` but it is not working too. And above throws a error:

`Cannot read property 'img' of undefined`

and i tried other way `let image = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#img');` this gives me:

`Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null`

What did i do wrong ? Any advice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem about your element is the fact that your `connectedCallback` doesn't "forward" the call to `super`. That should be the first thing in your method, so it would become:

```
  connectedCallback() {
    super.connectedCallback();
    this._imageHide();
  }
```

I am guessing that you just skipped a part from your code and that `pageInfo.title` is in fact a truthy value. But since I don't know when/how those values are set I am guessing that another issue might be that the `_imageHide` method runs from the `connectedCallback` and it might be too early for the tag to be actually stamped into the page.

Unless there's some complexity there about when these values are set, I am guessing you should be fine by simply delaying the call the shortest time possible, but wrapping it in a `setTimeout` without the second parameter. So in fact `connectedCallback` would be:

```
  connectedCallback() {
    super.connectedCallback();
    setTimeout(() => {
      this._imageHide();
    });
  }
```

And now the third problem would be the fact that the `this.$` "shortcut" is not available for elements that are conditionally added into the page. So you should use `querySelector`, like you said, or maybe `getElementById`, like:

```
let image = this.shadowRoot.getElementById('img');
```